# Run a c application on another platform

Tags: c, windows, dll, cross-platform

I am done with my application in c that implements a GUI - its a financial calculator that calculates optionprices (call and put)

No problem to compilate this and run the app.

My platform: **Windows XP - X86 32 bit processor.**

Maybe I am a bit naive - I copied the exe-file to a usb and installed it on my friends computer:

His platform: **Windows Vista - X86 64 bit processor.**

Yes - c is not like java (platform independent) but why not try :-)

When I tried to start the exefile I got an Error:

The program could not be executed because the libgobject-2.0-0.dll is missing.

So when I came back to my home I searched for this dll-file and its located in the bin-folder. What binfoler? I am used to se the full path to the file but all I can see is its located in the bin-folder.

So my questions:

1. What is this libgobject-2.0-0.dll? What is it doing?
2. where is it located - full path?
3. Finally _ how can I run this exe-file on that platform?

*I just want to learn c and how to make it compatible to other platforms.*

Is the answer to this question - recompile the code in the other platform?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use static linking then you don't have to worry about this

Answer (score 3):

> So my questions:
>
> 1. What is this libgobject-2.0-0.dll? What is it doing?

It's part of the GLib/GObject/GTK+ tryptichon of libraries. They are part of the GTK+ project which is an open source user interface and application framework. http://www.gtk.org

Some part of your program uses GObject functionality and hence depends on this library.

> 2. where is it located - full path?

Somewhere on your system. There's a plethora of possible locations. But that doesn't matter, simply copy it besides your `.exe` – that's the recommended place to put it to anyway. Oh, and be prepared to copy in a number of other DLLs as well.

> 3. Finally _ how can I run this exe-file on that platform?

Your problem is not a plattform problem, but a lack of proper distribution. You'd see the same problem if running on a different 32 Bit Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a C language problem, it's an application install problem. Copying an .EXE won't work in a lot of cases. What you need to use is a windows installer that will pick up all the dependent assemblies, such as the libgobject-2.0-0.dll and package them into a nice Windows installer file - an .MSI file.